# Angular2: How to get a reference to a ViewChild in a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component (`App`) that contains another component (`Comp`). `App` gets string content from a database and forwards it by `@Input()` to `Comp`. This string content can contain html tags like

```
Some text before <a>Click</a> Some Text after
```

In `Comp` this content is supposed to be rendered and some event listeners are supposed to be added. Therefor this content is added using `[innerHtml]`. Because `(click)` is removed in `[innerHtml]` a reference to the `a` tag is needed and a event listener is supposed to be added with `addEventListener`. But I can't find a way to reference the `a` tag since an `ElementRef` to a component doesn't contain `nativeElement`.

What is the best way to get this plunker running?
https://plnkr.co/edit/xVUu0LJ02YVnBO25Zr4j?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Direct DOM access is discouraged in Angular2**

Here's a hacky way to do it with direct dom access.

Define an event listener in the child comp and filter the event:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
         that.updateCounter.next(true);
      }
    });
```

then use an `EventEmitter` to update the counter.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vm44niH781j4mEQHDpLU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2, you want to make your nested components to communicate only to their direct parent / children.

you can create a click handler for your "a" tag in your component "Comp".

In your component Comp, you can create a @Output() variable (basically an EventEmitter), that you will fire in your click handler

In the main app component, you can listen to your new EventEmitter and handle the event.

For example :

in Comp :

```
@Output myClickEventEmitter: EventEmitter

aTagClickHandler (e) {
    myClickEventEmitter.emit(e)
}
```

in App template

in App Component :

```
myCompClickHandler(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I hope my syntax is correct here, and that it helped .

EDIT :

You should also be able to reference an inner component using the #variableName attribute in your a tag like that :

in template :

```
<a #variableName > </a>
```

in component :

```
@ViewChild('variableName') myATag;
```

Comment: As I said, the content comes from an external database. I can't edit the `a` tag. The event handling is very generic and depends where the component is used. Therefor it is necessary that the event comes from `App` and not from `Comp`

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstood your requirements. You can have a look at @echonax 's answer , but, as he said, "Direct DOM access is (strongly) discouraged in Angular2". For "cleanness" of code, but also for performance and side effects issues. Maybe if your string  is regular enough, you could rewrite the html ? Might be worth it.

Comment: Direct DOM access is also strongly discouraged in this project so I have to find another way. Currently I'm trying to expose the view to the parent component.