# Angular2 - How to render a button with click event dynamically

Tags: angular, datatable

I have a Web App in Angular2, in which I am using the SmartAdmin template.
One of my templates has a datatable.

For each record in the table, I want to have an 'Edit' button.

This is how I did it -

```
<sa-datatable #countryTable [options]="{
        ajax: 'assets/api/tables/datatables.filters.json',
        columns: [ {data: 'name'}, 
                   {data: 'position'}, 
                   {data: 'office'}, 
                   {data: 'age'}, 
                   {data: 'date'}, 
                   {data: 'salary'}, 
                   {defaultContent: '<button class=\'btn btn-default btn-xs edit-country-btn\' (click)=\'editClicked()\'>Edit</button>' } ] }"
       tableClass="table table-condenced table-striped table-bordered">
    .
    .
    .
</sa-datatable>
```

The problem is that the button is rendered, but the event is not bound to it. (The HTML is rendered as it is, without Angular2 directives).

I tried rendering the button using `render` instead of `defaultContent`. But that doesn't work as well.

**EDIT**

I tried to get the `edit-country-btn` elements from the DOM in order to bind them to the event, but I can't seem to fetch them:

In the component -

```
@ViewChild('countryTable') public countryTable: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    var b = this.countryTable.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button');
    console.log(b);
}
```

The result is a list of buttons, but not the edit buttons that I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind a click event to the body which will be activated for button elements (or if you want it to be more specific you can use id, class etc.),

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
      if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
         this.editClicked();
      }
    });
```

Similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579935/5706293

Answer (score 2):

Angular compiles statically, HTML added at runtime is not processed by Angular.

You can use

```
querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', editClicked.bind(this))
```

(after the button was added to the DOM)

Comment: I actually did try this, but I can't seem to get the edit button list. See my edit. Is `ngAfterViewInit()` the right place for this?

Comment: Perhaps it's not added yet. Try with `setTimeout(() => ..., 100)`.

Comment: This works. but how do I set the timeout such that it is foolproof? Right now, it doesn't work at 100, but works at 1000.

Comment: Using `setTimeout()` was just a way to figure out what the problem is. Now it's clear that `sa-datatable` does async initialization. You can try `setTimeout(() => ...)` (without a specific delay). If this works I'd just use that. A better way would be if `sa-datatable` provided an event when it's done initializing. If it doesn't work without a timeout, I'd consider echonax' approach.