# Ionic 2 - angular 2 listener on component

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a map page with some markers. That markers are created on a function of my component. In the markers info, I would like to add a link to another page. So on my component, where I create the marker, I'm doing something like this:

```
let text = "Some text <ion-label (click)='onViewUnidade'> My link </ion-label>";
```

That `onViewUnidade` function would redirecto to that another page. However, that function is not even called. Is my syntax incorrect? What's the best way to do that? Thanks!

---

EDIT: checked the possible duplicate, but still can't make it works.
Even if change the (click) listener for `onClick="onViewUnidade()"`, my function is still not executed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - How to render a button with click event dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688494/angular2-how-to-render-a-button-with-click-event-dynamically)

Comment: @echonax edited the question with more information. Thanks